# Add hline for groups outside of aestetic in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a line chart with metrics for different years and months. I want to add a median line for each month.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(52)

data <- tibble(
  date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2017-01-01"), to = date("2020-12-31"), by = "month")
) %>% 
  mutate(
    metric = rnorm(n(), mean = 5, sd = 2),
    month = month(date, label = TRUE),
    year = as.factor(year(date))
  )

ggplot(data, aes(x = month, y = metric, color = year, group = year)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

I tried using geom_hline() to do this but it only produces a line for the total median.

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = month, y = metric, color = year, group = year)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = median(metric), group = month))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

What is the easiest way to create a median line for each month? Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for...?

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = month, y = metric, color = year, group = year)) +
     geom_line() +
     geom_tile(data = function(df) df %>% group_by(month) %>% 
                                          summarise(metric = median(metric)),
               aes(x = month, y = metric), height = 0.05, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

Alternatively, thanks to @user20650's comment below, this also works...

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = month, y = metric, color = year, group = year)) +
     geom_line() +
     stat_summary(aes(x = month, y = metric), 
                  fun = median, 
                  geom = "tile", 
                  height = 0.05, 
                  inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

Comment: yes, but these line have different size? I suspect there are actually many lines for each month?

Comment: @FilipW No, they are all the same size - it is just the low resolution of this graphic. Try making `height` a bit bigger.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ave`.

I didn't get it if you need a median line for each year or through the months, so I will show you both.

---

### Median for each year

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = month, y = metric, color = year, group = year)) +
   geom_line() +
   geom_line(aes(y = ave(metric, year, FUN = median)))
```

[image]

---

### Median through months

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = month, y = metric, color = year, group = year)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(y = ave(metric, month, FUN = median), colour = "median"), size = 2)
```

[image]

---

EDIT:

since you are interested in a horizontal line, here you have an alternative solution:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = month, y = metric, color = year, group = year)) +
  geom_line() +
  stat_summary(aes(x = month,  y=metric), fun = median, geom = "point", shape = "-", size = 15, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: this is nice! But I would like to have horizontal lines that represent the median to make it clearer

Comment: okay, check my edit

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can simply create a new variable in your dataset with a median metric. Your first group observations by month, then calculate a median metric and then ungroup the data.

```
data <- data %>% group_by(month) %>% mutate(median_metric=median(metric)) %>% ungroup()
```

Once you do it, you just specify `yintercept` to vary by `median_metric`

```
ggplot(data )  +
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = metric, color = year, group = year))+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = median_metric))
```