# Why mean lines for each group wont appear on the plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

tl;dr
Wrong datatype for columns, but median and min works also correct for character types.

I can't add hline that represent mean for each category. My data:

The mean line does not show up on the graph, but other functions (median, minimum do).

```
head(dfWithMetrics)
              RMSE         R_squared Fold_number       Model
1 6.23760977376979 0.687050835336811           1 Simplest lm
2 5.92075361024118 0.711785658583921           1   Gam model
3 4.97390199786346 0.650664191560854           2 Simplest lm
4 5.21536823776451 0.690317431157077           2   Gam model
5 5.81616278223824 0.674206707505027           3 Simplest lm
6 5.28615205934741  0.69095063006211           3   Gam model
```

EDIT: according to comment I add output of dput to reproduce df.

```
structure(list(RMSE = c("6.23760977376979", "5.92075361024118", 
"4.97390199786346", "5.21536823776451", "5.81616278223824", "5.28615205934741"
), R_squared = c("0.687050835336811", "0.711785658583921", "0.650664191560854", 
"0.690317431157077", "0.674206707505027", "0.69095063006211"), 
    Fold_number = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3"), Model = c("Simplest lm", 
    "Gam model", "Simplest lm", "Gam model", "Simplest lm", "Gam model"
    )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried following code based on answer posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70018571/19656413.

```
R_squared_plot <- ggplot(data = dfWithMetrics, aes(x = Fold_number, y = R_squared, color = Model, group = Model, shape = Model))+
    ggtitle(TeX("$R^2$ per fold"))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_line(aes(y = ave(R_squared, Model, FUN = mean)), linetype="dashed")
```

[Plots using mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtqVq.png)

But if I change FUN to median or min code works as expected. Below output with `FUN=median`.

`[Plots using median](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqLNr.png)

Also linetype seems to be unused, but this is minor.

What the problem here? Why line for mean won't appear? I can add this lines manually, but I want this code be easily extensible.

Comment: From the image of your plot I would guess that your `R_squared` column is actually a character instead of a numeric. Perhaps that's the issue. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by sharing your data in a reproducible format using `dput()`, i.e. run `dput(head(dfWithMetrics))` and copy & paste the output into your post.

Comment: @stefan You've right. The columns seems to be character instead of numeric. I'm wondering why, this is really unexpected. I correct dtype and now it's works as expected. Thanks for your answear.